# Vueで円スライドバーで範囲指定をする際に最小～最大の範囲指定をしたい

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

添付の画像のように通常は最小値～最大値で範囲指定をすると思います。
それに加えて、最大値～最小値で範囲してできる方法を教えてください。
例えば340～20のような範囲を指定したいです。このとき実際の値は360を境界値として、340～360、0～20となる想定です。

以下のライブラリを使用して実装しようとしましたが、ダメでした。
https://github.com/soundar24/vue-round-slider

よろしくお願いいたします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 実際のコードも質問に含めておくと回答が付きやすいかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。試してみたライブラリを追加しました。